# Android - Errors in code that should be working

Tags: android, android-studio, indexoutofboundsexception

I have some code here for a calculator that I'm pretty sure should be working (I remember it working in the past), but it's acting up.

I've checked all the `arrayList.get()` to make sure they're pointing to the right index, and there are the correct number of `arrayList.remove()`'s per loop.

The only other thing I can think of is that potentially the `if` loop that checks if the result is a decimal or not (right down near the bottom of the method) is messing with things.

Here is the code:

```
public void onClickEquals (View view) {

    TextView textViewError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcPrevRes);
    TextView textViewCalcPrevRes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcPrevRes);
    TextView textViewCalcCurrExp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcCurrExp);
    TextView textViewCalcPrevExp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcPrevExp);
    double calc = 0;
    String calcOutputStr = "";
    String tempString = "";
    int c = arrayList.size();

    try {
        textViewError.setText("");
        //i.e. array [2,+,3,*,4,-,3] size(c) = 7, so [2,+,3,*,4,-,3]
        while (c != 1) {
            if (c > 3) {
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("×") || arrayList.get(3).contains("÷")) {
                    if (arrayList.get(3).contains("×")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2)) * Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(4));}
                    if (arrayList.get(3).contains("÷")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2)) / Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(4));}

                    //calc = 12 ;array = [2,+,3,*,4,-,3]
                    arrayList.remove(2); //[2,+,*,4,-,3]
                    arrayList.remove(2); //[2,+,4,-,3]
                    arrayList.remove(2); //[2,+,-,3]
                    arrayList.add(2, Double.toString(calc)); //[2,+,12,-,3]
                    c = arrayList.size(); // size(c) = 5
                } else {
                    //[2,+,12,-,3]
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) + Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) - Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("×")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) * Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("÷")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) / Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                    //calc = 14
                    arrayList.remove(0); //[+,12,-,3]
                    arrayList.remove(0); //[12,-,3]
                    arrayList.remove(0); //[-,3]
                    arrayList.add(0, Double.toString(calc)); //[14,-,3]
                    c = arrayList.size(); // size(c) = 3
                }
            }
            // size(c) <= 3
            else {
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) + Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) - Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("×")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) * Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("÷")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) / Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                //calc = 11
                arrayList.remove(0); //[-,3]
                arrayList.remove(0); //[3]
                arrayList.remove(0); //[null]
                arrayList.add(0, Double.toString(calc)); // [9]
                c = arrayList.size(); // size(c) = 1
                prevCalc = Double.toString(calc);
            }
            //CHECK IF DECIMAL - SHOULD BE OUTSIDE WHILE LOOP
            //check if calc is a whole number; if yes, convert to string and enter into tempString, remove decimal and enter into calcOutputStr ready for display on screen.
            if (calc % 1 == 0) {
                tempString = Double.toString(calc);
                if (tempString != null) {
                    tempString = tempString.substring(0, tempString.length() - 2);
                }
                calcOutputStr = tempString;
                arrayList.clear();
            }
            //if calc is a decimal convert to string ready for display on screen.
            else {
                calcOutputStr = Double.toString(calc);
                arrayList.clear();
            }
        }
            textViewCalcPrevExp.setText(textViewCalcCurrExp.getText()); //copy text from textViewCalcCurrExp to textViewCalcPrevExp
            textViewCalcCurrExp.setText(""); //remove text from textViewCalcCurrExp
            textViewCalcPrevRes.setText(calcOutputStr); //display calc
            stringInput = "";
            stringInputWithOp="";
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        textViewCalcPrevExp.setText(textViewCalcCurrExp.getText());
        textViewCalcCurrExp.setText("");
        stringInput="";
        stringInputWithOp="";
        arrayList.clear();
        textViewError.setText("ERROR");
    }
}
```

I'll give two scenarios to help illustrate my issue:

1. `arrayList = [2,+,2];` upon running this method, `textViewCalcPrevRes` displays `4`
2. `arrayList = [2,+,2,+,2];` upon running this method, `textViewCalcPrevRes` displays `ERROR`, due to the method throwing an exception and printing the stack trace in the console (see next code block). The really weird thing is that the `catch{}` statement should output `ERROR` to `textViewError` and not `textViewCalcPrevRes`.

Here's the stack trace outputted to the console in scenario 2:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
W/System.err:     at com.st1.u3141294.sparkscientificcalculator.sparkMain$override.onClickEquals(sparkMain.java:126)
W/System.err:     at com.st1.u3141294.sparkscientificcalculator.sparkMain$override.access$dispatch(sparkMain.java)
W/System.err:     at com.st1.u3141294.sparkscientificcalculator.sparkMain.onClickEquals(sparkMain.java:0)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Obviously it's throwing an IndexOutOfBounds Exception, however I'm really not sure how/why.

Any ideas please?

EDIT: Further "investigation" suggests that the origin of the exception is from this line of code (marked with `//-->`):

```
// size(c) <= 3
            else {
           //-->if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) + Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) - Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("×")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) * Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("÷")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) / Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
```

---

EDIT: @Code-Apprentice:

If we use scenario 2 as the contents of the `arrayList` (that is `[2,+,2,+,2]`), then my code should work. Following the trace:

First block of code run because `c = arrayList.size() = 5`, and there are no multiplication/division operators in the `arrayList`, so it would go to the `else` loop:

```
while (c != 1) {    
    if (c > 3) {
    //here is code only run if there are multiplication or division operators in arrayList
    } else { 
        if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) + Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
    }
        arrayList.remove(0); //bringing arrayList down to [+,2,+,2]
        arrayList.remove(0); //then [2,+,2]
        arrayList.remove(0); //then [+,2]
        arrayList.add(0, Double.toString(calc)); //then adding 4 (calc) to arrayList[0] would give [4,+,2]
        c = arrayList.size(); // therefore arrayList.size() = 3
}
```

Now, since `c = arrayList.size() = 3`:

```
// size(c) <= 3
        else {
            //4+2
            if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) + Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
        }
        //new value of calc = 6
        arrayList.remove(0); //gives [+,2]
        arrayList.remove(0); //gives [2]
        arrayList.remove(0); //arrayList is now empty: [null]
        arrayList.add(0, Double.toString(calc)); // arrayList populated with calc --> [6]
        c = arrayList.size(); // size(c) = 1
        prevCalc = Double.toString(calc); //puts this calculation into memory for next calculation if needed
```

Comment: Commenting to bump.

Comment: "Index: 1, Size: 0" This means the list is empty. You need to use the debugged to figure out why this is so when you expect otherwise.

Comment: If you need further help, please tell us which line causes the crash.

Comment: Unsolicited advice: findViewById() is expensive. You should do these calls once in onCreate() and save the references as field variables.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I edited the OP to show the code would be run. By my eyes it looks like nothing should be wrong. Look at the bottom of the post.

Comment: According to your comments, you call remove() three times when the list only has two elements. Clearly this is incorrect.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice where do you see that it has 2 elements? First or second block of code in my example?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the annotations in the comments. Have you run the debugger to see where the elements in the list differ from what you expect in this example?

Comment: All good, I just posted a solution thanks to Sarasranglt's suggestion. Now, @Code-Apprentice can I please ask you to elaborate on calling findViewById() once in onCreate()?

Comment: 1. Declare all view variable as fields instead of as local variables. 2. Call findViewById() for each one in onCreate() rather than your click listener. This will increase the response time for your calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, log ur arrayList size again and again in the code  . You'll get to know when its empty.

```
Log.d("Buggy List Size ",  arrayList.size()+"");
```

Comment: Can you please explain more how to implement this to debug the code? I'm a debugging newbie.

Comment: I figured it out, and you helped me fix my code! Thank you.

Comment: Also start learning debugging techniques . That will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I made a rookie mistake, the `CHECK IF DECIMAL` loop was inside the `while` loop, meaning that as soon as the first calculation had been made, it would attempt to output the result. Instead of calculating `2+2+2`, it only calculated `2+2` and then would clear the `arrayList`, causing the `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

Here is the fixed code (with the `CHECK IF DECIMAL` loop outside the `while` loop, like it should be)

```
public void onClickEquals (View view) {

    TextView textViewError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcPrevRes);
    TextView textViewCalcPrevRes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcPrevRes);
    TextView textViewCalcCurrExp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcCurrExp);
    TextView textViewCalcPrevExp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcPrevExp);
    double calc = 0;
    String calcOutputStr = "";
    String tempString = "";
    int c = arrayList.size();

    try {
        textViewError.setText("");
        //i.e. array [2,+,3,*,4,-,3] size(c) = 7, so [2,+,3,*,4,-,3]
        while (c != 1) {
            if (c > 3) {
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("×") || arrayList.get(3).contains("÷")) {
                    if (arrayList.get(3).contains("×")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2)) * Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(4));}
                    if (arrayList.get(3).contains("÷")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2)) / Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(4));}

                    //calc = 12 ;array = [2,+,3,*,4,-,3]
                    Log.d("BuggyListSizeB4Remove1", arrayList.size()+"");
                    arrayList.remove(2); //[2,+,*,4,-,3]
                    Log.d("BuggyListSizeB4Remove2", arrayList.size()+"");
                    arrayList.remove(2); //[2,+,4,-,3]
                    Log.d("BuggyListSizeB4Remove3", arrayList.size()+"");
                    arrayList.remove(2); //[2,+,-,3]
                    Log.d("BuggyListSizeAfter3", arrayList.size()+"");
                    arrayList.add(2, Double.toString(calc)); //[2,+,12,-,3]
                    c = arrayList.size(); // size(c) = 5
                    Log.d("BuggyListSize AfterCalc", arrayList.size()+"");
                } else {
                    //[2,+,12,-,3]
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) + Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) - Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("×")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) * Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("÷")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) / Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                    //calc = 14
                    Log.d("BuggyListSizeB4Remove1", arrayList.size()+"");
                    arrayList.remove(0); //[+,12,-,3]
                    Log.d("BuggyListSizeB4Remove2", arrayList.size()+"");
                    arrayList.remove(0); //[12,-,3]
                    Log.d("BuggyListSizeB4Remove3", arrayList.size()+"");
                    arrayList.remove(0); //[-,3]
                    Log.d("BuggyListSizeAfter3", arrayList.size()+"");
                    arrayList.add(0, Double.toString(calc)); //[14,-,3]
                    c = arrayList.size(); // size(c) = 3
                    Log.d("BuggyListSize AfterCalc", arrayList.size()+"");
                }
            }
            // size(c) <= 3
            else {
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) + Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) - Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("×")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) * Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("÷")) {calc = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0)) / Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(2));}
                //calc = 11
                Log.d("BuggyListSizeB4Remove1", arrayList.size()+"");
                arrayList.remove(0); //[-,3]
                Log.d("BuggyListSizeB4Remove2", arrayList.size()+"");
                arrayList.remove(0); //[3]
                Log.d("BuggyListSizeB4Remove3", arrayList.size()+"");
                arrayList.remove(0); //[null]
                Log.d("BuggyListSizeAfter3", arrayList.size()+"");
                arrayList.add(0, Double.toString(calc)); // [9]
                c = arrayList.size(); // size(c) = 1
                prevCalc = Double.toString(calc);
                Log.d("BuggyListSize AfterCalc", arrayList.size()+"");
            }
        }
        //CHECK IF DECIMAL
        //check if calc is a whole number; if yes, convert to string and enter into tempString, remove decimal and enter into calcOutputStr ready for display on screen.
        if (calc % 1 == 0) {
            tempString = Double.toString(calc);
            if (tempString != null) {
                tempString = tempString.substring(0, tempString.length() - 2);
            }
            calcOutputStr = tempString;
            arrayList.clear();
        }
        //if calc is a decimal convert to string ready for display on screen.
        else {
            calcOutputStr = Double.toString(calc);
            arrayList.clear();
        }
        //output to textViews
            textViewCalcPrevExp.setText(textViewCalcCurrExp.getText()); //copy text from textViewCalcCurrExp to textViewCalcPrevExp
            textViewCalcCurrExp.setText(""); //remove text from textViewCalcCurrExp
            textViewCalcPrevRes.setText(calcOutputStr); //display calc
            stringInput = "";
            stringInputWithOp="";
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        textViewCalcPrevExp.setText(textViewCalcCurrExp.getText());
        textViewCalcCurrExp.setText("");
        stringInput="";
        stringInputWithOp="";
        arrayList.clear();
        textViewError.setText("ERROR");
    }
}
```